# jQuery - find an element to handle with troubles

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do some regular click function, where I have to find an element outside of the clicked element. Here is some code:

```
<div class="options">
    <span class='comment_now'>kommentér</span>
</div>

<div class="write_comment_wrap">
    <form method="post" class="write_comment_form">
        <textarea class="write_comment" name="write_comment" placeholder="skriv din kommentar..."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="skriv" class="global_button">
    </form>
</div>​
```

JS :

```
$('.comment_now').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.write_comment_wrap').slideToggle();
});​
```

Nothing is happening. I've tried to make an alert to find out if I'm inside of the function. I guys I'm using the wrong traversing function.

Comment: Are there many comment forms? Many <div class="write_comment_wrap">?

Comment: Yes, lots of them :) That's why I'm trying to pick the closest()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
$('.comment_now').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.options').next('.write_comment_wrap').slideToggle();
});​
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/HwQLw/

Comment: This seems to work! But I have to click 2 times in a row on .comment_now before it'll slideToggle();... How come?

Comment: hmm, that's weird.. maybe it's something with my css or something?

Comment: When I'm using show(); it works like a charm. But when I use any of the slide effects like: slideToggle(); slideDown(); etc. I have to click twice for it to slide.

Comment: Google's 1.7.2, and UI 1.8.18

Comment: There IS only one click event. And it IS fired on the first click.

Comment: @mcgraph for some reason it's working now. I've used some position: absolute; maybe it did the trick, I don't know. Well, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

`.closest` is to find the closest element in the same dom tree, but in your case, `.write_comment_wrap` is sibling of `.comment_now` span's parent.

```
$('.comment_now').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.write_comment_wrap').slideToggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.comment_now').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.write_comment_wrap').slideToggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcVqf/

Answer (score 0):

`closest` traverses the DOM tree upwards. The DOM tree for `.comments_now` is:

```
   - body, etc.
     - .options
       - .comments_now
```

So `$(this).closest('.write_comment_wrap')` won't find you anything, as `.comments_now` does not have such an ancestor.

What you could do instead is:

```
 $(this).closest('.options').next('.write_comment_wrap').slideToggle();
```